# 4th order Runge Kutta method not working for coupled equations

Tags: c++, function, logic, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I have to apply the 4th order Runge Kutta method (RK) to the coupled equation in [handbook of marinecraft hydrodynamics and motion control](http://kashti.ir/files/ENBOOKS/HMCH.pdf), page 154, equation 7.33, to determine v and r for every iteration. the RK method works when I use the functions separately, i.e., when I use the functions in separate programs. I have converted the equations from matrix form to linear equations. `q1`, `q2`, `q3` and `q4` are coefficients of `v` and `r`
The RK method is given as a function and is called twice to find `v` and `r` values. I can obtain the correct range of values of `r` as when `rud` increases, the values of `v` and `r`  increase as well. when `rud` = `rudmax`, `v` and `r` should remain constant. however, `v` keeps increasing and doesn't stop. both `v` and `r` should be constant when `rud` = `rudmax`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double dvdt(double r, double v);
double drdt(double v, double r);
double RKv1(double to, double vo, double t, double h);
double RKr1(double to, double ro, double t, double h);



double xo = 0;    //initial X position
double yo = 0;    //initial Y position
double x1;      //final X position
double y11;      //final Y position
double ti = 0;  //initial time = 0
double tf;      //time entered
double dt = 0.01;   //time step (iteration time)
double rud = 0;   //rudder angle
double m = 3.27385 * pow(10, 11);   //mass of submarine (Kg)
double Iz = 2.31448 * pow(10, 12);     //moment of inertia of submarine (kg.m^2)
double xg = 10.3;   //x position of COG
double yg = 0;     // position of COG
double u = 10; // surge velocity
double v, vo = 0; //sway velocity
double r, ro = 0; // yaw rate
double psio = 0; //initial ship heading
double psi1;  //final ship heading
double rudmax; // max rudder angle
double au; //surge acceleration
double av; // sway acceleration
double ar; //angular acceleration
double X; //surge force
double Y; //sway force
double N; //turning moment
double h = 1;
//double q1, q2, q3, q4;
//matrices


//maneuvering and hydrodynamic coefficents
double Xu1 = -0.010087715;//-1.0467 * pow(10,-3);
double Yv1 = -0.290828106;//-23.889 * pow(10, -3);
double Yr1 = -0.008070039;//-1.0510 * pow(10, -3);
double Nv1 = -0.002928156;// 1.1531 * pow(10, -3);
double Nr1 = -0.056559574; //-0.50717 * pow(10, -3);
double Xu = -0.007115651;// -2.8763 * pow(10, -3);
double Yv = -0.35098699; //-38.948 * pow(10, -3);
double Yr = 0.091748747;// 2.0031 * pow(10, -3);
double Nv = -0.123433077;//-14.287 * pow(10, -3);
double Nr = -0.056559574;//-4.2267 * pow(10, -3);
double Yrud = -0.587323034;//1.4308 * pow(10, -3);
double Nrud = 0.991135206;// -0.71540 * pow(10, -3);

double a1 = m - Yv1;
double b1 = m * xg - Yr1;
double a2 = m * xg - Yr1;
double b2 = Iz - Nr1;
double det = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;

double q1 = (-Yv * (Iz - Nr1) / det);
double q2 = ((m - Xu1) * u - Yr) * (-m * xg + Yr1) / det;
double q3 = ((Xu1 - Yv1) * u - Nv) * (-m * xg + Yr1) / det;
double q4 = ((m * xg - Yr1) * u - Nr) * (m - Yr1) / det;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout; //for .CSV file
    fout.open("results2.csv", ios::out | ios::app);  //for .CSV file

    //cout << det<<"\n";
    /*cout << "surge velocity = ";
    cin >> */ u = 10;
    /*cout << "rudmax = ";
    cin >> */rudmax = 30;
    /*cout << "final time = ";
    cin >>*/ tf = 100;

    fout << "rud" << ", " << "ti" << ", " << "r" << ", " << "v" << "\n"; //for .CSV file
    while (ti <= tf)
    {
        v = RKv1(ti, vo, ti + 0.025, h);
        r = RKr1(ti, ro, ti + 0.025, h);


        fout << rud << ", " << ti << ", " << r << ", " << v << "\n"; //for .CSV file
        vo = v;
        ro = r;
        ti = ti + dt;

        if (rudmax > 0)
        {
            if (rud < rudmax)
            {
                rud = rud + 0.005;
            }
        }
        else if (rudmax < 0)
        {
            if (rud > rudmax)
            {
                rud = rud - 0.005;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------FUNCTIONS---------------------------------------------------*/

//functions for velocity and distance
double dvdt(double r, double v)
{
    //return(-Yrud * rud - ((-Yv * (Iz - Nr1) / det) * v + ((m - Xu1) * u - Yr) * ((-m * xg - Yr1) / det )* r));
    return(-Yrud * rud - q1 * v + q2 * r);
}

double drdt(double v, double r)
{
    //return(-Nrud * rud - (((Xu1 - Yv1) * u - Nv) * ((-m * xg + Yr) / det) * v + ((m * xg - Yr1) * u - Nr) * ((m - Yr1) / det) * r));
    return(-Nrud * rud - q3 * v + q4 * r);

}
//RK methods
//correction of rk method
double RKv1(double to, double vo, double t, double h)
{
    int n = /*(int)((t - to) / h)*/ 1;
    double k1, k2, k3, k4;
    double v = vo;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        k1 = h * dvdt(ro, v);
        k2 = h * dvdt(ro, v + 0.5 * k1);
        k3 = h * dvdt(ro, v + 0.5 * k2);
        k4 = h * dvdt(ro, v + k3);

        v = v + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

        to = to + h;
    }

    return v;
}

double RKr1(double to, double ro, double t, double h)
{
    int n = /*(int)((t - to) / h)*/ 1;
    double k1, k2, k3, k4;
    double r = ro;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        k1 = h * drdt(vo, r);
        k2 = h * drdt(vo, r + 0.5 * k1);
        k3 = h * drdt(vo, r + 0.5 * k2);
        k4 = h * drdt(vo, r + k3);

        r = r + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

        to = to + h;
    }

    return r;
}
```

the results are stored in the results2.csv file.

[snippet of the result. r (-28.59) remains constant whereas v (-84000) keep increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szpo6.png)

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. thanks!

Comment: My comments to your previous question still apply. Please consider to repair these.

Comment: You cannot apply the RK4 method to `v` and `r` independently. You have to apply it to the system as a whole, i.e., all operations have to be vector operations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann,H. Rittich thank you for your suggestions. I apologize for the late reply as i do not get notifications when comments on my post. I have made the changes. I have declared the variables as global variables. I have changed the approach for the problem. instead of converting the matrix equation to 2 linearised equations to find v and r seperately, i have used the matrix equation in my program to find v and r simultaneously in the same iteration. however I am unable to obtain the correct plot. I am not sure if I applied RK method correctly or not as both v and r vary with time t.